# What is RAC aware application?

Tags: database, oracle, database-design

I recently came across a question "is your application RAC aware?". I had to no clue about it. I tried checking the meaning of it but no where anyone has explained the concept. Everywhere they have started from step 2 i.e. how to do coding, configuration, etc. But no one talks about the "RAC Aware" as a concept.

Can someone give the basic idea of the concept here?

Comment: Real application  clusters - Google it -lots of computers to handle the database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle RAC (Real Application Clusters) is a Oracle clustered database, with high availability features and a lot more. See [here](https://www.oracle.com/lad/products/database/options/real-application-clusters/overview/index.html)

From my undestanding, a "RAC aware" application is an application which will be deployed and using an Oracle RAC environment. For clustered environments, sometimes applications need to take some special considerations, that will vary between providers.

In your case, it happens to be a document pointing exactly to your question

[Oracle RAC Database aware Applications - A Developer’s Checklist](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/availability/racdbawareapplications-1933522.pdf)